# Calculation of left-sided limit

Tags: limits

I have a problem with calculation of this limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}xe^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

I know the result is $-\infty$, but am unable to calculate it by hand. The $0^+$ limit is easy, I used L'Hôpital's rule.

Will you help me? thx

Comment: If you're okay with using L'Hopital's rule, you could just substitute $x\mapsto \frac1x$ or $-\frac1x$ and go from there.

Comment: It's an **odd** function, so if you can do it for $x \to 0^+$, you can deduce the result for $x \to 0^-$ immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: L'Hôpital's rule with the substitution $u=\frac1x$ should do it:
$$\lim_{u\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{e^{u^2}}{u}=\lim_{u\rightarrow-\infty}2ue^{u^2}\rightarrow-\infty$$
Applying l'Hôpital once.

Comment: If i do L'Hôpital's it is +inf * (-inf). If I do L'Hôpital's twice, it is +inf. If I derive "x" and "x" is from negative numbers, is it -1?

Comment: @naruto25 edited the answer and added explanations

Comment: isnt it 2*(-inf)*(+inf)? So it is undefined I think.

Comment: This indeterminate form goes to negative infinity. Picture two numbers being multiplied: one large and negative, and one very large and positive. The result is negative.

Comment: I thought that (-inf)*(+inf) is undefined. Well, it explains everything, thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

You can show this limit as follows using the inequality

- $e^t \geq 1+t$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$

So, you have

$$e^{\frac 1{x^2}} \geq 1+\frac 1{x^2}$$ 
$$\stackrel{\color{blue}{x<0}}{\Rightarrow} xe^{\frac 1{x^2}} \color{blue}{\leq} x\left(1+\frac 1{x^2} \right)=x +\frac 1x \stackrel{x \to 0^-}{\longrightarrow}-\infty$$